# Merge dataframe and filling to a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to merge 2 dataframes & return a matrix & ffilling at the same time.
My two dataframes are

```
AR = {"Supplier": ["A","A","A","B",],
      "Currency": ["AUD","AUD","USD","AUD"],
      "Day": [1,3,1,1],
      "Amount": [510,530,610,710]}
AR = pd.DataFrame(AR)

IntTable = {"Currency": ["AUD","AUD","AUD","USD","USD","USD"],
            "Day": [1,2,3,1,2,3],
            "InterestRate": [11,12,13,21,22,23]}
IntTable = pd.DataFrame(IntTable)
```

I tried this

```
Table = pd.merge_ordered(IntTable, AR, on=['Currency','Day'], 
                         how= 'outer', fill_method='ffill', left_by=['Day'])
```

**Result I get:**

[image: Result I get]

**Result I want:**

[image: Result should be]

Comment: I formatted your post for you. Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it. The easier to understand, the less of a chance for downvotes - and most people here care about silly internet points.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. So, is the question posted or do I have to do anything else?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what exactly you're trying to do. If I understand correctly, for each combination of supplier and currency in AR, you'd like to have all three days in the output?

Comment: @Roy2012, I am struggling too. Somehow I feel he needs a cartesian product rather than out join, but not exactly.

Comment: Yes,  for each combination of supplier and currency in AR, you'd like to have all three days in the output. Merge/join might not be the best code to use, I have to admit it. Please feel free to suggest

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to achieve what you want. I'm starting by creating the skeleton for the result:

- For each combination of supplier and currency in AR, you'd like to have all three days.
- Then, I'm filling in the relevant data:

```
    df = pd.merge(AR[["Supplier", "Currency"]].drop_duplicates().assign(dummy=1), 
             IntTable[["Day"]].drop_duplicates().assign(dummy=1), on = "dummy").drop("dummy", axis=1)
    df = pd.merge_ordered(df, IntTable, on = ["Day", "Currency"])
    df = df.sort_values(["Supplier", "Currency"])
    df = pd.merge_ordered(df, AR, on = ["Supplier", "Currency", "Day"], fill_method='ffill')
    print(df)
```

The output is:

```
  Supplier Currency  Day  InterestRate  Amount
0        A      AUD    1            11     510
1        A      AUD    2            12     510
2        A      AUD    3            13     530
3        A      USD    1            21     610
4        A      USD    2            22     610
5        A      USD    3            23     610
6        B      AUD    1            11     710
7        B      AUD    2            12     710
8        B      AUD    3            13     710
```

Comment: Great. Could you please accept my answer for future generations? (click the grey checkmark next to the answer, turning it to green).

Comment: Good job, @Roy2012. Finally you understand it, I was still struggling :)